# Values coming NULL after importing table from Excel

Tags: arcgis-pro, csv

I'm importing a CSV file into ArcGIS Pro, I've used geoprocessing tool XY Table to Point but values have come in null. Column type is double in ArcGIS Pro. Highlighted is the column which imports null from Excel. Changing of data type doesn't work. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: You need to provide some more information about the data you try to import from excel or csv.

Comment: looks like csv is not formatted (or a column has a value with a comma.) you need to standardise your data first to avoid this issue

Comment: You had a tag for ArcPy but have not mentioned it in your question body so I’ve removed it.